How to properly quit QEMU using Java and telnet
I've got QEMU process running on local machine and using telnet monitor. I'd like to be able to connect to QEMU via telnet (from inside java application) and send "quit" command, but it seems to not respond.
Here the code snippet:
try (Socket monitor = new Socket("127.0.0.1", port)) {
    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(monitor.getOutputStream(), true);
    out.println("quit\\r\\n ");
} catch( IOException e ) {
    //
}

When I try to do the same from terminal, it works as expected (telnet localhost port, then Telnet greetings message shows, and then QEMU terminal line appears)
I've also tried to use running this script to end QEMU process:
expect << EOF
spawn telnet localhost port
send "quit\\r\\n"
expect -re ".*>"
EOF

and it works too.
What do I do wrong?

"quit\\r\\n " - shouldn't it be "quit\r\n" ?

Wait until the other side is ready to receive your command?

Why the catch is empty? Log any exception with stacktrace. Edit the question to add if it throws.

@aled catch block is empty for example purposes, there is logger.error() in the original code. Anyways, no exception is thrown here

@SteffenUllrich I've tried changing it leaving only one escape char, that's not the case

@aled I've tried to wait till the other side is ready to receive, using both Thread.sleep() and reading socket's InputStream till Telnet greetings message appears, still not working.

Don't use sleep to synchronize processes.
